# Problem while compile less in custom theme of magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, less

In folder `app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\web\css\_styles.less`
It already `@import 'source/lib/_lib.less'` this will define `variables/_colors.less`
But i can't figure out why magento raise undefine variables in module `Magento_Theme` inside of my custom theme
Is it process compile less in module first then go to web folder of theme?
[image]
Testing with Magento 2.0.2 and xampp on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

On your custom theme copy this file:

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/web/css/source/_variables.less
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/[PACKAGE]/[THEME]/web/css/source/_variables.less
```

This file above contains the variable **@copyright__background-color** that you need.

Or you can add this variable on the top of your **_styles.less** but I don't recommend it.

So run these commands:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage cache:clean &&
mage cache:flush &&
mage indexer:reindex &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy ; mage setup:static-content:deploy -f;
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create 
`app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\web\css\_theme.less`
and also test this by putting some css in it.

```
.page-header {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

after this deploy the static content

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the use of LESS in Magento 2 is an important skill. First of all, check out that if you are using the correct syntax or not. When a LESS file runs, it automatically generates CSS. Here is the basic example to understand how a LESS converts into CSS.

Let’s take a LESS file with the following code:

```
@radius: 20px;

#somediv {
    -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
    -moz-border-radius: @radius;
    border-radius: @radius;
}
```

The above code will be compiled in CSS as:

```
#somediv {
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

In this example, the LESS file with a variable `@radius` will assign a value of `20px` wherever `@radius` variable will be invoke in LESS file and generate the CSS file.

Now, if we talk about how to use custom LESS in a Magento 2 store, you will have to start with creating a basic module with `custom.less` file in `app/code/Module_Namespace/Module_Name/view/frontend/web/` and after adding the custom code in it, enable the extension and perform necessary actions using below Magento 2 CLI commands:

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

For the reference, please have a look at this blog post:
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/use-less-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your own Less files don't have the same name as the Less files from the Luma theme! If so, they will overwrite the Luma files.

So, if you are using a file named variables.less, and it only contains three variables, it will, after deploying, overwrite the luma theme variables.less and all the Luma variables will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I have added 
*`@copyright__background-color: @color-gray-middle4;`* 
to my *_theme.less* file according following link, its worked for me.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12398